# Cannot connect mongoDB server via Mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb

When I try `mongo` command on command prompt it gives me the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-09-05T19:05:18.728+0530 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6

2020-09-05T19:05:18.733+0530 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-09-05T19:05:18.733+0530 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

I am new in MongoDB and cannot understand how to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

you need first to start mongo db service

I installed mongoDB via Brew, so i need to launch the command:

```
brew services start mongodb-community@4.4
```

and then launch `mongo` command to connect to MongoDB server